# scroll to specific element from iframe to parent window with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I need, when the page in my iframe reload to go on a specific element in the parent window.

I find some solution to go to the top of page, but no to a specific element..

for example to go to top of page :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window.parent).scrollTop(0,0);
});
```

it work perfectly..

So I try something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window.parent).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".mytargetelement").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

to try to scroll to specific element..  but no result.. seem it can't get the offset..

any help are welcome..

Thank's

Mickael

Comment: You can try simple `$(window.parent).scrollTop($(".mytargetelement").offset().top);`

Comment: thank's, but seem not working.. still get TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined
 

$(window.parent).scrollTop($(".tableoffers").offset().top);

Comment: Since you are using iframe element your selector (`$(".tableoffers")`) might be incorrect.Verify if the object exits.

Comment: the selector exist and is unique. I also try with another, same result.

Comment: Then $('#ifr').contents().find('#submitButton').offset() should work, as long as the code is called after the iFrame is loaded and the frames are on the same domain.

Comment: not sure to understand your code.. it look like a a code to find offset of a button inside of an iframe... but seem the reverse is expected, from the iframe to the main window..